# How to Get This Version on a file and not have it undone when checking in

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

I need to revert to an older version of a file in Azure Devops:

**1) I go to the history and say get this version of the file**

**2) I then check it out and then check it in**

I have also reversed these steps, checking it out first then getting the version I need.

In both instances visual studio undoes my changes at check in time.

Other than manually modifying the file with a space or something, how can I accomplish getting an older version of a file and then checking it in?

Answer (score 0):

Just share the detailed steps of mine here, to for you have a check:

**1)** Connect project in Visual Studio, open `Team Explorer` => `Source Control Explorer`:

[image]

**2)** Located to your repository, then open `History`:

[image]

**3)** Select one specific changeset that you want to revert to, and **double click** it. In the Team Explorer section of right panel, click on Rollback:

[image]

**4)** Change back to Source Control Explorer and open corresponding directory after **refresh**. You will see the `edit, rollback` displayed in `Pending change` column. Make it selected, then click on `Check in` from icon bar:

[image]

**5)** Add comment in `Team Explorer`, and click on `Check in`. Now, you will see it can be succeed to check in:

[image]

*Note: If you enable the `Gate check in` in Azure devops build pipeline, here the `check in` can only be available and successful after the corresponding build succeed.*

Comment: That rolls back the whole changeset though and not a single file.

Comment: @MikeCheel Nope, in step 4, I said make it selected. Here the “it” means the specific item(file). Select the single item, the one that is pending rollback, then choose `check in` from icon bar. Also in step 5, the VS wills also prompt one message that are you sure to rollback this item?